# Is it possible to pass a js function to an event handler constructor?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The JS function below:

```
function ShowFax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebServices/SendFaxService.asmx/SaveFaxData",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#<%=cSendFax.FindControl("dDIVFax").ClientID %>').show();
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Should be passed as an argument into the event handler constructor below:

```
Navigation.PHQ2_SendFax += new Navigation.CommunicationsEventHandler();
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Did you tried and failed, or some unexpected results? Also what you mean _"event handler constructor "_?

Comment: I've spent all day searching through the net to find out how to pass a javascript function into an event handler. Basically, i need to pass a method name into the parentheses but i'm not sure how to do that when the method is a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the name of the function as an argument:

```
Navigation.PHQ2_SendFax += new Navigation.CommunicationsEventHandler(ShowFax);
```

Where you can simply call it by using the argument's name (or store the function to a variable and use it later):

```
CommunicationsEventHandler = function(eventFunction)
{
    eventFunction();
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly if the method is in the .cs file. But ShowFax() is a js function, written in the aspx file.

Comment: Sorry, but your question did not make that clear. It does not state where those functions are located. I was wondering what c# and asp.net have to do with it...

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Thank you for pointing that out, I’m new to asking questions and these pointers are really helpful. My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the right way to do it but i solved the problem by creating a method in the code behind which calls the js function and then i used that method as my argument.

Method in code behind:

```
protected void ShowFax(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "ShowFax();", true);
}
```

Event Handler constructor:

```
Navigation.PHQ2_SendFax += new Navigation.CommunicationsEventHandler(ShowFax);
```